# Can I post a question about where to find data for skeletal 2D chemical structures?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I would like to post a question about where to find data for 2D skeletal chemical structures.  Is this forum a reasonable venue?

I have found a number of websites which provide structural data in a standard format.  There is, however, a particular style of skeletal diagram which involves showing correct bond angles, stereospecificity and emphasis of the geometry of the molecule that I'm currently not able to reproduce.  What I would like to ask the community is whether there is a place to find data which are already in this style, or whether the individual preparing the graphics typical configures the finer details of the drawing in order to achieve the specific style alluded to above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Especially in the context of [cheminformatics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cheminformatics) we have had questions about [databases](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/databases) before, which were considered on topic. (Data mining questions using databases are not on topic.) See for some example [Free chemical reactions database](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/71827/4945) and linked questions.
We also had a question about structural representations, e.g. [Algorithm used by PubChem to determine the 2D layout assignment for Compound entries?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/71275/4945)

I can't yet tell, what exactly you would like to know, but I think it falls within these examples and should be on topic. Receiving an answer on the other hand is, as usual, not guaranteed. Be specific in your query, add an example or two, and I would expect the question to be well received. However, please browse the questions that already exist to avoid asking a duplicate question. It's also a good idea to link to questions that ask a similar thing, and lie out the differences. In particular [Free API to view 2D representation of Molecules](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/94774/4945) could be of interest here.

Comment: Thanks very much, very helpful.